# Getting Value from particular index in 2d vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have made a 2d vector using :

```
 std::vector<std::vector<int> *> hp;
```

I want to initialise hp  vector and get the data from particular index for the same.

```
for eg,
Getting the values from hp[2][2];
```

Please do help

Comment: Why not `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`?

Comment: Yes You can do that but I have used that pointer so that i want to associate it with another vector so that any change in that particular vector  reflect  back in my 2d vector.

Comment: I would create first the `std::vector<std : : vector<int>>` and then afte adding individual vectors you can get a reference (or pointer) to them. That way you have all your data in one place and you can do `vec [i][j]` easily

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> *> hp =
    {
        new std::vector<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
        new std::vector<int> { 4, 5, 6 }
    };

    for ( std::vector<std::vector<int> *>::size_type i = 0;
          i < hp.size(); i++ )
    {
        for ( std::vector<int>::size_type j = 0; j < hp[i]->size(); j++ )
        {
            std::cout << ( *hp[i] )[j] << ' ';
//          std::cout << hp[i]->operator[]( j ) << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        

    for ( auto &v : hp ) delete v;

    return 0;
}
```

For commented and uncommented statements within the inner loop the program output will be the same and look like

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

Comment: I know it is not relevant to the question but IMO it is bad form to provide an answer containing a `new` without a corresponding `delete`.

Comment: @Chris Drew Though the question about how access elements of the vector nevertheless I added delete. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>*> hp
```

defines a std::vector containing pointers to objects of type

```
std::vector<int>
```

As ravi mentioned, you probably want

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> hp;
```

But if you insist on having a vector with pointers,

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>*> hp;
(*hp[2])[2] // retrieves third value from third std::vector<int>
```

Remark: In C++11 (also called C++0x) you don't need the spacing between the ">" (as I wrote in the examples).

Answer (score 0):

If these are pointers to vectors that are owned elsewhere:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main() {

    // Create owning vector
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> h = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};

    // Create vector of pointers
    std::vector<std::vector<int>*> hp(h.size());
    //auto get_pointer = [](std::vector<int>& v){return &v;}; // C++11
    auto get_pointer = [](auto& v){return &v;};  // C++14
    std::transform(h.begin(), h.end(), hp.begin(), get_pointer);

    // Output value in third column of third row
    std::cout << (*hp[2])[2];
}
```